# String decoding

Tags: string, decode

I have this string that should contain XML information, but I don't know how it has been encoded.

`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`

The above shown string is part of an XML file customized for an application written by a supplier of mine. I have access to XML but I don't know how to decode such string contained in a node on the file.Is there a way to decode it and/or to understand which coding has been applied on it?

Comment: the above shown string is part of an XML file customized for an application written by a supplier of mine. I have access to XML but I don't know how to decode such string contained in a node on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's base 64. 
On unix, you can decode with `base64`. 
On Windows, you'll probably need to script it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64 qw ( decode_base64 );

my $stuff = <DATA>;
open( my $output, ">", "something.out" );

#print decode_base64($stuff);
foreach ( split( //, decode_base64($stuff) ) ) {
    printf( "%02x ", ord($_) );
    print "\n" if $_ eq "\n";
}
```

Based on what you've given though, that decodes to some binary data type. I can't tell what file format *that* is supposed to be though.

It starts with the byte pattern:

```
1f 8b 08 00
```

Which referring to: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Means it's a gzip compressed file.

Easy way is just save `something.out` as `something.gz` and use whatever gzip tool you've got. (You might be able to perl it with something like `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip`)

Comment: Great! I confirm. It's base64 and contains a gzip file.

Comment: OK. So if we save that 'something.out' to `something.gz` you should be able to use gzip stuff to decompression